# Service method is not called when passing heavy parameter object

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, xamarin.ios, request-timed-out

I am working on xamarin.ios. I am consuming web service. I have added the web service reference with my project. Now I am consuming the service methods. Everything is working fine. There is a method in service in which I pass an object of data which contains the all information of data. But it works only some time. And rest time I get error of "Request Time out". 
I found that if I remove some items from passing objcet to make the parameter object lighter then it works, but if I don't make it lighter I get the "Request Time out" error.

I am getting this problem only when I am trying to consum it in xamarin.ios. It is working fine in xamarin.android.

I am not able to find the actual problem. Can any one tell me if the problem is from my code or the problem is from server or service side?

Comment: Are you using the same parameter in the service call from android from ios? If the request takes too long to respond, you need to at least extend the timeout perior of your request.

Comment: Yes using same data and same object for both android and ios. I tried to increase the timeout value but nothing works

Comment: Do you have a specific exception that was caught?

Comment: "Request Time out" is the exception that I was getting in catch block